# Не подключается .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, ubuntu

Доброго времени суток.

Заметил, что у меня не обрабатывается .htaccess.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, в какую сторону копать, чтобы узнать, почему такое может быть?
Чуть ниже приложил конфиг виртуалки:

```
<virtualhost *:80>
    ServerName www.site.com
    ServerAlias site.com *.site.com
    ServerSignature Off
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^site\.com [NC]
    RewriteRule ^/(.*) http://www.sitet.com/$1 [L,R]

    <Directory "/home/site/%-3/public_html/">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    VirtualDocumentRoot /home/site/%-3/public_html/
    ErrorLog /home/site/.logs/site.com/error.log
    CustomLog /home/site/.logs/site.com/access.log combined
    ServerSignature On
    Options FollowSymLinks Includes MultiViews ExecCGI
    UseCanonicalName Off
</virtualhost>
```

Также пробовал `<Directory />` вынести за пределы `virtualhost`, и не помогло.
В `apache2.conf` ничего не менял на эту тему.

```
AccessFileName .htaccess

<FilesMatch "^\.ht">
    Require all denied #В этом может быть проблема?
</FilesMatch>
```

**Обновление**

Частично понял, в чем была проблема.

```
<Directory "/home/site/%-3/public_html/">
```

Это надо нормально прописывать, т.е.

```
<Directory "/home/site/www/public_html/">
```

Например... А есть ли способ использовать только 1 запись а не клонировать, а то неудобно как-то получается, хотелось бы, чтобы работало `<Directory "/home/site/%-3/public_html/">`.